How can i optimize or reduce for loop for this nested python dictionary?
I have this nested dictionary in python
flag_dict = {
    'modl1': {
        'slide1': {
            'screens': {
                'screen1': {
                    'mp4_1': 1,
                    'mp4_2': 0,
                    'mp4_3': 1
                }
            }
        },
        'slide2': {
            'screens': {
                'screen1': {
                    'mp4_1': 0,
                    'mp4_2': 1,
                    'mp4_3': 0
                },
                'screen2': {
                    'mp4_1': 1,
                    'mp4_2': 0,
                    'mp4_3': 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'modl2': {
        'slide1': {
            'screens': {
                'screen1': {
                    'mp4_1': 1,
                    'mp4_2': 1,
                    'mp4_3': 0
                }
            }
        },
        'slide2': {
            'screens': {
                'screen1': {
                    'mp4_1': 0,
                    'mp4_2': 1,
                    'mp4_3': 1
                },
                'screen2': {
                    'mp4_1': 1,
                    'mp4_2': 0,
                    'mp4_3': 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



I tried this approach to get inner part of dictionary and update count
count = []
for modl1, mv in flag_dict.items():
    # docs on isinstance vs type https://switowski.com/blog/type-vs-isinstance/
    if isinstance(mv, dict):
        for slide1, sv in mv.items():

            for screen1, scv in sv['screens'].items():

                key_lis = []
                for key, val in scv.items():

                    if 'mp4' in key:
                        key_lis.append(key)
                for i in key_lis:
                    if scv[i] == 1:
                        count.append(scv[i])
print(count)

I would like to know if i can minimize for loops in my code so a part of code efficiency could be enhanced. As I searched online regarding certain post and answers but still cannot have concrete solution to this any help will be useful.

why is this necessary? if isinstance(mv, dict):? Isn't it always a dict? What is the source of this data? What is count supposed to be?

From a quick glance it looks like you could do away withe the final loop. just move the  if 'mp4' in key: statement to be under the key_lis.append(key) line.
edit: tried a multiline code block and it was ugly. switched to a more compact explainer

similarly, why is if 'mp4' in key necessary?

A recursive approach is likely to be appropriate here. Whether it's more efficient (or not) is a matter for evaluation. There would certainly be less code. Having said that, your output seems rather strange. What you're doing is finding keys that have "mp4" in them and if the associated value is 1 you add 1 to a list. But what use is that list. It's just full of 1s and you have no idea where they came from

@juanpa.arrivillaga it is a small block of code where  count  is calclulated  and we do further calculation

@SIGHUP if the structure of the nested dictionary is regular, I think just looping is better, if you are actually searching through a tree-like arbitary structure then maybe recursion would make sense

@Nava that doesn't really answer any of my questions.

@juanpa.arrivillaga we will have mp3 audio path too in same dict so just a check with key  between mp3 and mp4 but i guess we can have better way to check dict keys

If your dictionary doesn't contain any lists (as is the case in the sample data) you can use a very simple recursive approach.
The following code will recurse through nested dictionaries looking for keys that contain the substring "mp4" and if the associated value is 1 then 1 will be added to a list (for no apparent reason):
def find_mp4(d, count):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            find_mp4(v, count)
        else:
            if "mp4" in k and v == 1:
                count.append(1)
    return count

print(find_mp4(flag_dict, []))

Output:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Afterthought:
It may be that the intention is to count the number of keys containing the substring "mp4" that also have a value of 1.
If that's the case then:
def find_mp4(d):
    def _find(d, c):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                c = _find(v, c)
            else:
                if "mp4" in k and v == 1:
                    c += 1
        return c
    return _find(d, 0)

print(find_mp4(flag_dict))

Output:
11

